# How to pass a returned variable from a keyword to another of same and different class

Tags: robotframework

How to pass a returned variable from keyword to another keyword of same robot class also to keyword from another robot class.
below is my code.

coverage.robot

```
 Choose a coverage type
    [Arguments]   ${coverage}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  60s   1s  Click Element   xpath=//span[contains(text(),'${coverage}')]
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  60s   1s  Click Element   ${continue button}
    Log To Console   ${coverage}
    [Return]   ${coverage}
```

I am appending the "coverage" variable to a xpath , and returning the same value , and i want to pass this value to the other keyword in  different robot class.

delay.robot

```
Get a Delay Reason
    eclaims_coverage_page.Choose a coverage type
    ${covergae type}  set Variable  ${coverage}
```

Answer (score 0):

your keyword will return value get it into variable

like  this ->  ${coverage}=   Choose a coverage type 
now 
set it as dictionary and pass it(dict) to your other keyword like

```
set to dictionary  ${Data Provider}
...  coverage      ${coverage}
Get a Delay Reason  ${Data Provider}
```

after this you have to get value of your variable from dictionary
so pass it as key. and its value will be fetched as follows
this should be in your second keyword. and it will look like this

```
Get a Delay Reason   [Arguments]    ${Data Provider}
${coverage}=    Get from dictionary  ${Data Provider}  coverage 
eclaims_coverage_page.Choose a coverage type
${covergae type}  set Variable  ${coverage}
```